# Bonitasoft Bonita Newbie: Showing and editing data entered by user before

Tags: bonita

I'm new to Bonitasoft Bonita Studio.

I want to design a form with UI Designer with three input boxes: name, surname, order.

The input shall be thrown to another pool via a message. In the second pool, there is a "catch message event". The data that was entered by the user should be shown in another task/form in this pool and it should be possible to edit the inputs.

That should be very easy, but I can't get this mini-project to work. Could anybody help me please?

Main question is: How can I show the data that was entered before in a new form?

I use a business data model and have a business variable for each pool. I try to use "throw message" and "receive message" to pass the business variable data from one pool to the other pool, but unfortunately i can't use the data from first poll in the second pool.

Could anybody help me please?

- Pool 1: Business variable called "bestellung"
- Pool 2: Business variable called "kundenbestellung"
- In pool 1: throw message event. message variable "nachrichteninhalt" takes value of "bestellung"
- in pool 2: receive message event. business variable "kundenbestellung" takes valoue of message variable "nachrichteninhalt"
- in pool 2: task to show data of "kundenbestellung" (i tried it with normal Bonita-function and with REST-API, but nothing works)

Screenshots: (sorry, I'm not allowed to include pictures directly into this topic as I'm to new in this forum)
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OohR6.png)
[Pool 1 variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOxn7.png)
[Pool 1 message throw event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCRKW.png)
[Pool 2 variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9ocd.png)
[Pool 2 Receive message event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0PfU.png)
[Pool 2 show data task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5IKM.png)
[Pool 2 show data task form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kJZc.png)

Comment: Please post your code or screenshots.

Comment: I updated the question, now there are links to screenshots

Comment: Maybe you can share your .bos file?